# How do I update a certain column when a value from the same row equals a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to do this for hours now, and I can't quite get my head round it. I have a table called "requests" that has the columns "deletekey" and "deleted". "deletekey" is a random unique number (data-type text), and "deleted" is by default set to 0 (data-type boolean), and when the user inputs the deletekey, it changes "deleted" to 1.
But I can't get it to work.
Here is the code I have, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
$key = $_GET["delkey"];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
$query = 'UPDATE requests SET deleted = True WHERE deletekey = "$key"';
$result = $link->query($query);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections! Please use prepared statements or at least escape the input with `real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was going to do some vulnerability scanning after I got it to work, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help, and will also provide protection against SQL injection:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
$key = $link->real_escape_string($_GET["delkey"]);
$query = sprintf("UPDATE requests SET deleted = 1 WHERE deletekey = '%s'", $key);
$result = $link->query($query);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks very much. I will accept this as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `WHERE deletekey = '$key`', then? The `deleted` field could NEVER equal whatever's in `$key`, since deleted is a simple boolean, and $key is probably an int/char/varchar-type thing.

Note that you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Stop working on this sort of code until you've learned about the problem and how to avoid it.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copied out some old code. I've updated the OP to show the changes. I know about SQL injections and stuff, and I was going to fix that when I actually had it working. I thought the injection-fixing code might have been the problem so I removed it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Its deletedkey = "$key" right ? and not deleted = "$key" :

```
$key = $_GET["delkey"];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
$query = 'UPDATE requests SET deleted = true WHERE deletedkey = "$key"';
$result = $link->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
 $key = $link->real_escape_string($_GET["delkey"]);
 $query = "UPDATE `requests` SET `deleted` = true WHERE `deletedkey` = $key";
 $result = $link->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

the query is a string. And to add a variable to a string you need to type

```
$query = 'UPDATE requests SET deleted = True WHERE deleted = '".$key."';
```

the difference is how to make a variable put into the string. You have to do like this in php.
 `$query = "randomtext ". $randomvar ." ";`
 where the important point is to `". $var ."` inside the string. This i similar to javas `"+ var +"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'UPDATE requests SET deleted = 1 WHERE deletekey = "$key"';
```